# iOS8 Simulator: Proxy authentication pop up not being shown

Tags: ios, proxy, ios-simulator

The corporate network which I am using is having "proxy" set up to connect to internet. I made the necessary changes in Network settings in mac and I am able to see websites loading in Safari (I have entered the credentials and saved in KeyChain also), but when I try to access the sites via iOS simulator, the connection fails and asks for authentication but the problem is that no pop-up is being shown so that I can enter the username and pwd. I have seen the pop-ups in iOS6 simulator and it used to work. I would like to know whether I need to do some changes specifically to iOS simulator to get this working?

I tried turning on `Settings -> Developer -> Allow HTTP services`, this works when you are in an open network (home), but in corporate network auth error is being show in a plain html page and there is no pop-up to enter credentials. I also tried restarting the simulator none of this fixed the issue .
Below is the error

```
Error Code :407 Proxy Authentication Required. Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. (12209).
```

Thanks in advance

-anoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned as a known issue in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html):

> iOS Simulator does not support the use of network proxy servers that
>   require authentication. (14889876)

Comment: Ok then that means I need to ask for a new network out of firewall