# How can i set proxy in simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, proxy, ios-simulator, ios11

I am using proxy internet network on my Mac which uses **Web proxy(HTTP)** & **secure web proxy(HTPPS)** along with *username & password*.

[image]

***In my mac internet works fine, but on simulator it asks again(continuously pop up) for proxy, i have entered correct one on simulator but can't access internet on simulator.***

[image]

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901615/ios8-simulator-proxy-authentication-pop-up-not-being-shown